# Get all of the children of a specific parent in a rose tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to get all of the children of a specific root by a given name in Haskell.

The declaration of the tree:

```
data Rose a = Empty | Branch a [Rose a] deriving (Show, Eq)

sample2:: Rose String
sample2 = Branch "/" [ Branch "dir1" [ Branch "file1" [Empty]
                                     , Branch "dir3" [Empty]]
                     , Branch "dir2" [ Branch "file2" [Empty]
                                     , Branch "file3" [Empty]]]
```

and what I have tried:

```
childrenOf _ Empty = []
childrenOf name (Branch x xs) = if name == x then xs else childrenOf name xs
```

I want to call `childrenOf "dir1" sample2` and get `["file1", "dir3"]`

However, I get the error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main ( tree.hs, interpreted )

tree.hs:47:1: error:
    * Couldn't match type Rose t' with [Rose t]'
      Expected type: t -> [Rose t] -> [Rose t]
        Actual type: t -> Rose t -> [Rose t]
    * Relevant bindings include
        childrenOf :: t -> [Rose t] -> [Rose t] (bound at tree.hs:47:1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain that are children of a given directory with:

```
childrenOf :: Eq a => a -> Rose a -> [Rose a]
childrenOf _ Empty = []
childrenOf name (Branch x xs) = if name == x then xs else concatMap (childrenOf name) xs
```

This will produce the *direct* branches of all `Branch`es with the given name as `Rose` elements. You can also obtain the corresponding names with:

```
names :: [Rose a] -> [a]
names xs = [ x | Branch x _ <- xs ]

namesOfChildren :: Eq a => a -> Rose a -> [a]
namesOfChildren name = names . childrenOf name
```